# Using array elements to do a search and replace all using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say, I have a string

```
'I am abc1, my age is abc2 and I live in abc3, abc1'
```

and array which looks like

```
['abc1/xyx1', 'abc2/xyx2', 'abc3/xyx3']
```

I'm trying to do a **search and replace all** on the string using each element of the array in below fashion

```
replace abc1 by xyz1, abc2 by xyz2 etc..
```

i.e. after the script runs the output string will be

```
I am xyz1, my age is xyz2 and I live in xyz3, xyz1
```

This is what I tried thus far

```
var myString = 'I am abc1, my age is abc2 and I live in abc3, abc1';
var myArray = ['abc1/xyx1', 'abc2/xyx2', 'abc3/xyx3'];
for (var i=0; i<=myArray.length; i++){
var a1 = myArray[i];
var xs = a1.split("/");
var new1=xs[0];
var new2=xs[1];
var replaced = myString.replace(/new1/g, new2);
}
document.write(replaced);
```

But it is not working. Can anybody help?

Comment: one thing to fix, I think, is that <= should be <. There is more to fix, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you loop one too much, take `i < myArray.length` and you need the value of the variable as regular expression.

You could use a constructor and build a new regular expression object.

At last, you need to replace the same string and assign to the same string, otherwise you hae replaced, but you get only the last replacement back.

```js
var myString = 'I am abc1, my age is abc2 and I live in abc3, abc1',
    myArray = ['abc1/xyx1', 'abc2/xyx2', 'abc3/xyx3'],
    i, xs, new1, new2;

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    xs = myArray[i].split("/");
    new1 = xs[0];
    new2 = xs[1];
    myString = myString.replace(new RegExp(new1, 'g'), new2);
}

console.log(myString);
```

Comment: I haven't seen you using `for` loops in a while. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach.

For first a split the `keys/values` and get a new array (`keyValue`) which holds the old and new words. Then I iterate over the `keyValue` and replace the `text` by it's values.

```js
var text = 'I am abc1, my age is abc2 and I live in abc3, abc1';
var words = ['abc1/xyx1', 'abc2/xyx2', 'abc3/xyx3'];

var keyValue = words.map(item => {
  var arr = item.split('/');
  return [arr[0], arr[1]];
});

keyValue.forEach(item => {
  text = text.replace(new RegExp(item[0], 'g'), item[1]);
});

console.log(text);
```

Comment: could you mind explaining your method a bit, I am new to javascript so did not understand your method,

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `words` array usign [String.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and in every loop split the element `w` with [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to create an array variable `a` with the two indexed elements that you need to create a regular expression and call [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
var text = 'I am abc1, my age is abc2 and I live in abc3, abc1';
var words = ['abc1/xyx1', 'abc2/xyx2', 'abc3/xyx3'];

words.forEach(function (w) {
  var a = w.split('/');
  text = text.replace(new RegExp(a[0], 'g'), a[1]);
});

console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach:

```js
var text = 'I am abc1, my age is abc2 and I live in abc3, abc1';
var words = ['abc1/xyx1', 'abc2/xyx2', 'abc3/xyx3'];

var result = words.reduce((text, word) => {
  var [ oldWord, newWord ] = word.split('/');
  return text.replace(new RegExp(oldWord, 'g'), newWord);
}, text);

console.log(result);
```